# ¿Por qué el compilador no reconoce la función removeAt?

Tags: android-studio, array, kotlin

Trato de remover el elemento de índice 4 del arreglo "myArray" usando la función cuyo prototipo es: "fun removeAt(index: Int)" pero al tratar de compilar el programa el compilador me devuelve este mensaje:

[image: Salida del compilador]

Por lo que entiendo del mensaje es que falta un paréntesis pero al comparar con el prototipo de la función me doy cuenta que no es así por lo que supongo que el compilador no reconoce esta función.

Nota: Estoy desarrollando con Kotlin en la última versión de Android Studio con todos sus complementos actualizados en Linux Mint.

```
package com.mouredev.kotlinparaprincipiantes

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        leccionArrays() //llamado de la función

    }
private fun leccionArrays() { //declaración de la función

        val name = "Joshua"
        val surname = "Cervantes"
        val company = "Samsung"
        val age = "32"

        val myArray: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf<String>()

        myArray.add(name)
        myArray.add(surname)
        myArray.add(company)
        myArray.add(age)
        myArray.add(age)
        myArray.add(age)

        println(myArray)

        myArray.addAll(listOf("hola,","soy Goku"))
        println(myArray)

        val myCompany : String = myArray[2]
        println(myCompany)
        myArray[5] = "Qué hay de nuevo viejo";
        println(myArray)

        myArray.removeAt( index: 4 ) //Aquí está el problema

        println(myArray)

    }
}
```

Comment: Quítale el `index:` eso no es parte del código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes dejarlo como

```
myArray.removeAt(4)
```

o si lo que quieres remover esta dentro de una variable

```
myArray.removeAt(index)
```